# MySQL limit left table with join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM (`bf_discussion`) JOIN `bf_discussion` as b ON `b`.`parent` = `bf_discussion`.`id` WHERE `bf_discussion`.`projec_id` = '1' LIMIT 10
```

I'm attempting to select 10 discussions from the database.  Each of those discussions may have an infinite amount of children (referenced by the parent_id).

How can I limit the LEFT table to only 10, while allowing the child discussions to be retrieved with no limit?

(I'm using this in Codeigniter, so if there's a good solution within codeigniter that would be perfect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subselects are typically not ideal, but how about this query?  It will return at most 10 discussions with your specificed project_id, but also will return all child discussions for those parent discussions.

```
SELECT
parents.*, b.* 
FROM 
(SELECT * FROM bf_discussion 
  WHERE projec_id = 1 
  LIMIT 10) parents
LEFT JOIN bf_discussion b ON parents.id = b.parent
```

Comment: It's a little hard to tell how to fix this without understanding your schema better.  Maybe try SELECT DISTINCT?

Comment: Never mind, just saw your comment.  Thanks @Adam.  I'll take a look.

Comment: just add a GROUP BY whatever you want after the LEFT JOIN.

Comment: @Adam, you may also want to specify the columns you want (instead of `SELECT *`).  It makes sense that this would return duplicate columns because you're selecting * from the same table twice.

Comment: But I want all columns present in both parents and children, how do I handle that?

Comment: If that is the case, you need to alias the column names.  For example, `SELECT parents.id AS parent_id, b.id AS child_id, ....`